# LCM of the Two Numbers

Tags: java

Guys I found this code in online,used to find L.C.M of the two numbers but I couldn't understand the `gcd()` function.

when I try with a input `a = 2,b = 3`.It's showing 6 but when I do debugging myself I can't get the answer. I am struct here `if (a == b) return a`;

can you please help me to understand it's functionality. Please update with step by step functions

// Java program to find LCM of two numbers.

```
class Test
{
    // Recursive method to return gcd of a and b
    static int gcd(int a, int b)
    {
        // Everything divides 0 
        if (a == 0 || b == 0)
           return 0;

        // base case
        if (a == b)
            return a;

        // a is greater
        if (a > b)
            return gcd(a-b, b);
        return gcd(a, b-a);
    }

    // method to return LCM of two numbers
    static int lcm(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a*b)/gcd(a, b);
    }

    // Driver method
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int a = 15, b = 20;
        System.out.println("LCM of " + a +" and " + b + " is " + lcm(a, b));
    }
}
```

Comment: LCM of same numbers is the number itself.

Comment: Please read [this](http://grammarist.com/spelling/its-its/).

Comment: FWIW, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm for all the gory details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From Wikipedia** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor):

In mathematics, the greatest common divisor (gcd) of two or more integers, which are not all zero, is the largest positive integer that divides each of the integers. For example, the gcd of 8 and 12 is 4.

**Using Euclid's algorithm**

Formally the algorithm can be described as:

> gcd(a,0)=a
>
> gcd(a,b)=gcd(b,a mod b)
>
> where
>
> a mod b = a - b [ a / b ]

If the arguments are both greater than zero then the algorithm can be written in more elementary terms as follows:

> gcd(a,a)=a
>
> gcd(a,b)=gcd(a-b,b), if a > b
>
> gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,b-a), if b > a